# Differences in JSON serialization when loadAll() and loadById(Long id)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, spring-restcontroller

I have created Folder class (java springboot), which describes many levels folders' structure for bookmarks managing:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
**public class Folder** implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(
            generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
            property = "id")
    private Folder parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Folder> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;

    private String path;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "folder", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Bookmark> bookmarkList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
**public class Bookmark** implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String url;

    private String description;

    /**
     * parent folder
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Folder folder;
}
```

And my problem is that I can see differences in serialized JSON when loadAll() and when loadById(Long id):

```
@Service
@Transactional
**public class FolderService** {

    private FolderRepo folderRepo;

    @Autowired
    public FolderService(FolderRepo folderRepo) {
        this.folderRepo = folderRepo;
    }

    public void save(Folder folder) {
        folderRepo.save(folder);
    }

    public List<Folder> loadAll() {
        List<Folder> folderList = folderRepo.findAll();
        return folderList;
    }

    public Folder loadById(Long id) {
        Folder folder = folderRepo.findById(id).get();
        return folder;
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bookmarks-app")
**public class FolderControllerRest** {

    private FolderService folderService;

    @Autowired
    public FolderControllerRest(FolderService folderService) {
        this.folderService = folderService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/folders/all")
    public List<Folder> getFolderListAll() {
        List<Folder> folderList = folderService.loadAll();
        return folderList;
    }

    @GetMapping("/folder/{id}")
    public Folder getFolderById(
            @PathVariable(name = "id") String id
    ) {
        if (!"undefined".equals(id)) {
            Long folderId = Long.parseLong(id);
            return folderService.loadById(folderId);
        } else return null;
    }

}
```

Namely, the difference is ex. in folder.id=2.

When I load all using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/bookmarks-app/folders/all",
        data: {},
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON"
    });
```

the parent entity is **serialized to its "id" number** (as I wanted),

but when use ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/bookmarks-app/folder/2",
   data: {},
    method: "GET",
   dataType: "JSON"
 })
```

the parent entity is **serialized to the object** (screenshot below).

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAiem.png)

Comment: I think you are missusing @JsonIdentityInfo, the doc says "@JsonIdentityInfo allows to serialize a POJO by id when it is encountered second time during serialization. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missusing @JsonIdentityInfo, the doc says

> @JsonIdentityInfo allows to serialize a POJO by id when it is encountered second time during serialization.

Then in a 'list' mode you get the id, in a single mode you get the whole object.

Maybe you should Use a TypeAdaptor to get the id

Comment: I am not sure if it is a professional solution, but works ;) It means, that I reached now what I wanted.  `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id") 
 @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)  private Folder parent;`  So @Tokazio, thank you for your help!